# autodiscover on exchange 2010 (and automatic replies)

Tags: exchange-2010

There seems to be a problem with autodiscover on my exchange 2010 server.

From outlook, I was previously getting an SSL Cert error, but that seemed to be related to my firewall.  I have seemingly fixed that - I do not get the cert warning popup anymore, but automatic replies are still not working:

`Your automatic reply settings cannot be displayed because the server is unavailable.  Try again later.`

When I run Test Email AutoConfig, I get a few red flags, such as:

Autodiscover to https://exchange.localdomain.local/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml failed (0x800004005)

I am not sure if this problem is due to a misconfiguration on the exchange server, or an SSL Certificate problem.

My SSL cert includes both external and internal autodiscover FQDNs.

Event viewer has the following:

```
Log Name:      OAlerts
Source:        Microsoft Office 14 Alerts
Date:          1/25/2012 10:15:38 AM
Event ID:      300
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      jwilliamsWS.sxp.local
Description:
Microsoft Outlook
Your automatic reply settings cannot be displayed because the server is currently unavailable. Try again later.
P1: 301837
P2: 14.0.6029.1000
P3: 3lia
P4: 0x8004010F

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft Office 14 Alerts" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">300</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-01-25T16:15:38.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>412</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>OAlerts</Channel>
    <Computer>jwilliamsWS.sxp.local</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Microsoft Outlook
</Data>
    <Data>Your automatic reply settings cannot be displayed because the server is currently unavailable. Try again later.
</Data>
    <Data>301837
</Data>
    <Data>14.0.6029.1000
</Data>
    <Data>3lia
</Data>
    <Data>0x8004010F
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 2):

Often times, you can use Microsoft's Exchange Connectivity Tests to test Autodiscover and find out slightly more human readable errors with Microsoft KB Links.
https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/